# Cook Top Temperature Too Hot

Tags: electrical, kitchens, appliances, stove-top

I have a GE glass top drop in electric cook top (JP655) in my kitchen. Over the past week I have noticed that one of the burners is med-high to high regardless of what the knob is set at. Does anyone know of a potential cause or fix? I hope to not have to replace the whole unit.

Comment: The *controller* for that element has probably failed; the heating element itself is probably OK. The controllers are not cheap, although they vary in price, but it makes sense to put in a new one.

Comment: In my 25-year-old GE slide-in range (standard not glass top) all four surface units have lost the low end, that is they do not heat at all on the lower 1/5 or so of the range, but do control above that. I just live with it. But the type of failure you describe is different and it makes sense for you to put in a new controller for that one unit.

Comment: @JimStewart is something like this what you are referring too? GE called it the control switch. https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/vz3U2sZjdrcFxnzcx7oedO4xNE1vrWCP-J1niZR3llrsmLyKVqN7b6xr7VdRKrfUhrWGj2saqrGxf_b1CjaW9uPuehSNl_hRhjM2n11nxCD9js8=s0-d-e1-ft#http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/dBoAAOSwhQhY0vA-/s-b275x275.jpg

Comment: Yes. It is my diagnosis that is the fault and should be replaced. You should be able to find a youtube video showing how it is done or it may be obvious.  What is the price of this part for your range?

Comment: @JimStewart $58 through GE but I got one for $24 on eBay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The surface element controller has *probably* failed. Replace it. Personally I would use only a genuine GE part, but you may be able to get a genuine GE part cheaper than from GE. But if you already have a non-GE part on order you may as well try it. These parts cannot be easily tested with a meter by a DIYer. One just puts it in the range and sees if it works.

Note that your range will have different controllers for different sized burners, at least that is the case for mine.

Comment: If you want some insight into how these controllers work see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_regulator. See here about the different types of electric surface elements https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_stove